# Specify more than one directory in Web.Config's Location Path element

Tags: asp.net, path, web-config, location

In my ASP.NET's Web Config file I have the following location elements defined:

```
  <location path="">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="dir1">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="dir2">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The example above is specifying that all directories will be locked down to anonymous users except the two directories dir1 and dir2.

I'm curious if there is a syntax that I can use that will allow me to define more than one directory within one location element. For example, it would be convenient if we could do something like this...

```
  <location path="dir1,dir2,etc">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Looks like it used to be documented as allowing a comma separated list of paths, but they fixed the documentation rather than implementing the documented feature. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104010/location-path-attribute-in-web-config-doesnt-accept-multiple-paths

Comment: @Triynko https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104010/location-path-attribute-in-web-config-doesnt-accept-multiple-paths not found

Answer (score 16, accepted):

sorry, but path property doesn't allow to use ","
so you must write  tag for all path,
Or you can create web.config in each directory.

Answer (score 44):

You cannot specify multiple elements in the path attribute, but you can make use of the configSource attribute.

For example, the following original web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="form1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form3.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form4.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form5.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form6.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Can be replaced by the following equivalent web.config, allow.config, and deny.config files:

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="form1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="allow.config" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="allow.config" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form3.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="allow.config" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form4.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="deny.config" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form5.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="deny.config" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="form6.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="deny.config" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

allow.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

deny.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authorization>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

The usefulness of this approach increases as the number of allow/deny rules in each section increases.

Comment: Would I be able to simplify even further and only have lines for location with the configSource set there? So it would basically be just a list of locations?

Comment: @Ray: When I tried that, I got `Unrecognized attribute 'configSource'`.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to set path to a specific folder.
For example we have some aspx pages:

- /data/pages/form1.aspx
- /data/pages/form2.aspx
- /data/pages/form3.aspx

By creating this rule in web.config:

```
<location path="data/pages">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
                <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

All resources in `data/pages` will be affected.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. so went with the normal way of creating separate tags, no other BETTER solution.