# How to stop IIS going through .net to serve up images (favicon.ico).

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-express

I am writing a .Net MVC website, and using IIS express.

How do Is stop images from being served up through the .Net pipeline. I appricate I can ignore the route by doing this: `routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico")`. But I don't want the code to be hit at all.

I tried adding this to the `system.webServer` section in the web.config

```
<handlers>
   <add name="StaticFile-ico" path="*.ico" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
</handlers>
```

But this has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279643/prevent-iis-from-serving-static-files-through-asp-net-pipeline

Comment: I don't think it is `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is set to `false`. And I'm not sure .ico is included in the set of ignored  extensions?

Answer (score 0):

From:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

On IIS 7 it's only the first couple requests to the static file that miss the kernel cache, assuming the request meets kernel caching requirements.

**However** since you've used iis express you will not get kernel caching, its not supported in iis express.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is quite old, but I had this same problem on an Azure website. I [found a way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx) to tell IIS to ignore /favicon.ico requests, as my favicon.ico is set using meta tags.

You just need to add a route and tell IIS to ignore the request:

```
<rule name="block favicon" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="favicon\.ico" />
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="1" 
    statusReason="The requested file favicon.ico was not found" 
      statusDescription="The requested file favicon.ico was not found" />
</rule>
```