# MVC3 Site on IIS7.5 - how do I make static content available outside session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-404

I have a MVC3 site with static images served nicely from /Content/images to users of the site, but I get a 404 if I try to access them **outside a session**.

This is problem for icons and small branding assests used in Facebook dialogs, as they quite naturally 404 when the third party page references them.

I added the following into a web.config in the /Content folder, but no dice:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

These are only small files and while I could get them onto a third party CDN, it makes versioning more complicated.

I am thinking that I may need to either configure IIS to bypass ASP.NET routing OR create a /assets folder and add in something like `routes.IgnoreRoute("assets/{*pathInfo}");` in Global.asax.

Best plan?

Martyn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent IIS from serving static files through ASP.NET pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279643/prevent-iis-from-serving-static-files-through-asp-net-pipeline)

Comment: So, after following Chuck's suggestion, which is a nice way to indirect the image refs anyway, I then realised that a filter we have on the production server was causing the behaviour. Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered putting these assets on a sub domain?

In the past I've put images on a different domain: images.mydomain.com

Comment: Hmmm, that's a thought. I might have a look at ways of doing that with minimal change to the site.

Comment: @MartynBrearley When I did it, we left the image structure inside of the site, but when we created the IIS applications we mapped the image folders to the root of the images.domain.com address. This give you the flexibility to move the images to cdn or cloud without a huge impact on the site.

Comment: Nice. So does that require a CNAME for images? I tend to use the simlpest DNS settings possible then leave them well alone ;)

Comment: I was thinking of an A record. If you used the CNAME you'd be back to the same issue you have now with not getting the images unless there is an active session.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more an issue around your session code and less about how to configure IIS. In theory, static file hosting "just works" through IIS – same as dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but I'm not sure i quite understand your answer. I think the crux of my problem is that every incoming URL is processed by the MVC routing system, which is looking for /Controller/Action.

Comment: By default, the routing system will not route if a physical file exists at the target url.