# ASP.NET MVC3 HttpApplication doesn't fire events like BeginRequest, EndRequest, PostAcquireRequestState

Tags: events, iis-7.5, global-asax, httpapplication

ASP.NET MVC3 HttpApplication doesn't fire events like BeginRequest, EndRequest, PostAcquireRequestState etc. So it works fine but it doesn't fire events! I have tried to reinstall asp.net via aspnet_regiis - but there was no luck. Also i have tried to put events to Application_Start the same result.

I published web site via Web Deploy.

The interesting thing is - i have created new MVC project for testing purposes, deploy it and it works - HttpApplication events work perfectly.

Configuration:
WINDOWS 2008R2, IIS 7.5, ASP.NET MVC 3, all updates were installed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Example of subscribtion to HttpApplication events:

```
public MvcApplication()
 {
    EndRequest += MvcApplication_EndRequest;
    PostAcquireRequestState += MvcApplication_PostAcquireRequestState;
    PostAuthenticateRequest += MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
 }
```

Comment: I found - what was the problem! When i was exploring my web.config file, i saw the following parameter:
system.webServer->modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"
When i switch on runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests - HttpApplication events start working.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty good article on this: http://forums.asp.net/p/1306960/2572147.aspx#2572147

It should be a better solution than turning on managing of all requests by managed handlers. The latter is not very interesting for performance.

Answer (score 0):

As you saw from my comments i found a solution, but it's not complete solution, because it should work with `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"`, probably because i don't want, that static content will be involved in integrated pipeline - it's performance cost effective!
So i found real solution thanks to Kev: [Prevent IIS from serving static files through ASP.NET pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279643/prevent-iis-from-serving-static-files-through-asp-net-pipeline)