# How to remove static files from asp.net pipeline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have an issue. I need to switch current project from classic to integrated mode. The main blocked issue i have faced - static files go through asp.net pipeline. Yes, i know - this is standard behavior for integrated mode. 
But how could i do this only through configuration, i mean web.config. Current project has asp.net web form part and asp.net mvc part. So in my case i need to handle extensionless urls and *.aspx. I need something like this:

```
<location path="JS">
   <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
           <!-- here i will remove all modules -->
        </modules>
       <handlers>
           <!-- removing unnecessary handlers -->
       </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

But this code doesn't work. Are there any solutions for my case.  I have forms authentication, so if i turn it only for managedHandler - it will work for aspx part, but will not work for mvc part. If i put preCondition="", i.e. it will handle all request, my forms authentication functionality will work for static files, which i don't need.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279643/prevent-iis-from-serving-static-files-through-asp-net-pipeline ?

Comment: Yes, i did. BTW the second answer didn't correct, you can't override authentication value without changing applicationhost.config.