# Accessing Session in Authorization Event of Imageresizer

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, imageresizer

I'm trying to implement custom authorization in a MVC 4 application for ImageResizer (3.3.2) and everything works fine until I try to access session variables.

In global.asax I've added the following event listener to the pipeline:

```
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage += (m, c, args) =>
{
    // check authorization only for asset path
    if (args.VirtualPath.IndexOf("/Assets/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
    {
        // HttpContext from parameter
        // c.Session is always null

        // Static access
        // HttpContext.Current.Session is also null
    }
};
```

As noted in the code, Session is always null. Is there a way to configure the module to be session enabled or any other way to access session variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The FormsAuthentication module isn't configured to run for .jpg requests in your applcation. You can change this at the FormsAuthentication module level, or [enable RAMMFAR (which can compromise performance for other static requests)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279643/prevent-iis-from-serving-static-files-through-asp-net-pipeline) is essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but I have RAMMFAR enabled already. From your link to Scott Hanselman's blog I see that Session comes after HttpModule, so it seems not possible to access session within the module.?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right - Session state isn't available until the ProcessRequest phase, which is too late to be of use. You should be able to access all authentication and authorization data, however.

Comment: Yeah, authentication data I can access. My problem is, that I have a session state variable that determines which assets are available to the user. But if it is not possible, then I go with a less restrictive approach and ignore the current session state. Thanks for your effort. I Accept for the link to Hanselman's Blog.