# IIS 8 - Static file requests going through managed pipeline in spite of runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application that works fine in my local Cassini server and it also worked fine when I last tested it against IIS 7.5 a few months ago.

My web.config looks like this (irrelevant sections removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>

        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <!-- 2880 minutes is 48 hours -->
            <forms loginUrl="~/Welcome/Login" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" />
        </authentication>

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />

        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*"     path="*.asmx" />
            <add verb="*"        path="*.asmx"             validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add verb="*"        path="*_AppService.axd"   validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </httpHandlers>

        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule"     type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </httpModules>

    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule"     preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule"                               type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory"            preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"        path="*.asmx"             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"        path="*_AppService.axd"   type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource"                  preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"               preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"        path="UrlRouting.axd"     type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </handlers>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="Views\Shared\Iis404.htm" responseMode="File" />
        </httpErrors>

    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I'm now deploying it to IIS 8 on an Azure VM and requests for static content, e.g. `/Styles/style.css` go through the managed request pipeline, and because I have an authentication system in-place it means that those requests get blocked and replaced with my application's login screen.

I found this QA ( [Prevent IIS from serving static files through ASP.NET pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279643/prevent-iis-from-serving-static-files-through-asp-net-pipeline) ) and I changed `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` to `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">`, however that didn't fix it: requests to `/Styles/style.css` still caused my ASP.NET MVC code to be invoked (it invokes the Login action on my WelcomeController class, which fails because now the `Controller.User` property returns null).

I'm not aware of any changes in IIS8 that would trigger this - but how can I fix it anyway?

Update:

I added this to my Global.asax.cs but it didn't work:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Styles/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
```

Update: I've installed IIS 8 on my Windows 8 Enterprise laptop and to my surprise, it works as-intended on there - so there's some configuration difference between my Windows 8 laptop and the Server 2012 Azure VM. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I began looking for differences between the IIS configurations of my local machine and the Azure VM and I found the solution:

I had overlooked the <kbd>IIS > {website} > Authentication > Anonymous</kbd> configuration: on the Azure VM it was set to <kbd>Specific user</kbd> for a user that didn't exist! Whereas in my local IIS it was set to <kbd>Application pool identity</kbd>.

I changed it to <kbd>Application pool identity</kbd> and now it works as-intended.

I'm surprised IIS didn't give me any other error messages or a more helpful way to diagnose the problem. Hmpf.