# Application_BeginRequest and static files?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

`Application_BeginRequest` gets called when static files are served in my development using Visual Studio 2013. How can I stop `Application_BeginRequest` from been called when serving static resources?

Comment: You can't.    You can add code in that blcok to only execute basedon the url requested, but you can't stop it from firing.

Comment: @DavidStratton - maybe Daniel asks for [runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning)? OR maybe something else... not exactly clear what "static files" mean.

Comment: Static files would be things like images, etc.  Items that are not code/dynamic like aspx, ashx, asmx, etc.

Comment: @DavidStratton can you show me an example on how to filter those requests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent IIS from serving static files through ASP.NET pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279643/prevent-iis-from-serving-static-files-through-asp-net-pipeline)

Comment: @UserControl Solution did not work for MVC5.

Comment: Can you add the content of `system.webServer/modules` section to your post? It may help.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was in Web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```