# ConfigSource on Location element in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, configsource

Ok, so I am going through one of the company's websites and trying to clean up the web.config using the ConfigSource attribute on some elements.

One of the biggest areas of the web.config is a list of locations with authorization values for almost all pages on the site.

I cant seem to find a way to put them all in one config, am I really limited to making a configsource for each location element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they do require a config source each, ah wells. Please let me know if this is incorrect, but I cannot find anything otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple pages use the same configuration, you can reference the same file in the configSource attribute as illustrated in the my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16346330/1414000) to the question [Specify more than one directory in Web.Config's Location Path element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4608764/1414000).