# ASP.NET Forms Authorization not working for per page setup

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm building a webforms application, separating pages into folders, authorizing web-pages within these folders using the web.config, authorizing pages to authenticated users only and allowing certain pages to certain roles.

I have a 'beheer' folder in which the page1.aspx - page6.aspx reside. I also have a web.config in that folder which is shown below.

I'm logging into the system as a user have the role 'Admin', which would mean that all pages should be available to me, if I go to page3, page4, page5 or page6 it works just fine, but going to page1 or page2 it doesn't work, I get a unauthorized message, even though page2 and page3. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <!-- Deny all unauthenticated users -->
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="Page1.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Page1,Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Page2.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Page3,Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Page3.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Page3,Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Page4.aspx,Page5.aspx,Page6.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Are all pages located on the same folder?

Comment: yes, all in the same subfolder

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you actually have the Admin role assigned. This part seems wrong:

```
<location path="Page4.aspx,Page5.aspx,Page6.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

You can't specify more than one resource on the path element. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608764/specify-more-than-one-directory-in-web-configs-location-path-element) for more information.

Try changing it into this:

```
<location path="Page4.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Page5.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Page6.aspx" >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,UserAdmin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```