# How to exclude files from authorization in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, authorization, web-config

I have web.config's spread throughout my app that sets authorization like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Authors" />
      <allow roles="Editors" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I need to provide access to all `*.sitemap` files regardless of the authorization permissions in the web.config's. Is this possible, hopefully just set once from the root web.config?

Comment: It shis what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608764/specify-more-than-one-directory-in-web-configs-location-path-element

Comment: It helps but it still doesn't tell me what entry I need to override the above rules.