# <location> Config not loading from an external file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

Taking inspiration form these two posts

- [Keep your .config clean with external config files](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/16/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx-)
- [How can I simplify my Web.config file?](https://learnable.com/books/the-asp-net-2-0-anthology-101-essential-tips-tricks-hacks/preview/how-can-i-simplify-my-web-config-file-a64852b)

I am trying to load config for my multiple location nodes which I have used to allow anonymous access.

```
<location configSource="AnonymousAccess.config" path="Content"></location>
<location configSource="AnonymousAccess.config" path="Scripts"></location>
```

and my AnonymousAccess.config had the following data in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<location>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

I am placing the location element at the right place which I confirmed from this msdn link

[image]

I get a 'Configuration Error'. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the configSource attribute on `<location>` element, but on `<authorization>` and `<compilation>` elements.

See associated question here: [Specify more than one directory in Web.Config's Location Path element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608764/specify-more-than-one-directory-in-web-configs-location-path-element)

```
<location path="Content">
  <system.web>
    <compilation configSource="AnonymousCompilation.config" />
    <authorization configSource="AnonymousAccess.config" />
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Scripts">
  <system.web>
    <compilation configSource="AnonymousCompilation.config" />
    <authorization configSource="AnonymousAccess.config" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

And you would have the 2 config files:
AnonymousCompilation.config :

```
<compilation debug="true" />
```

And AnonymousAccess.config :

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```