# ASP.NET web.config Forms Authentication, deny anonymous users, allow anonymous access for single files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am reading this tutorial here: http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2007/08/mixing-forms-based-and-windows-authentication-in-aspnet/

this part is interesting:

> 3. Create 3 files: Login.aspx, WebLogin.aspx, WinLogin.aspx. These will be the only 3 files which can be accessed without any credentials. You can allow anonymous access through your Web.config like this:

but the section under that is blank :(

So my question is, how do I allow anonymous access to my Login.aspx, WebLogin.aspx and WinLogin.aspx ?

Comment: Your question is already answered, look at:

1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608764/specify-more-than-one-directory-in-web-configs-location-path-element

Comment: @MrDywar, while the question you reference deals with the same web.config section as the answer to this question, it is not the same as this question and the answer is not related at all.  I'm sure there probably are duplicates to this, though.

Comment: @ps2goat why? first link - show correct syntax with authorization, second - how to add rule on multiple files.

Comment: @MrDywar, sorry, it looked like a single link to me, and I only clicked the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your web.config. You will need this repeated for each page you want everyone to have access to (3 in your case).

```
    <location path="Login.aspx">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
```

Comment: What's the difference between your and other already provided solution?

Comment: is this correct? `<system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login"></forms>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="~/Login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>`

Comment: Use `Login.aspx` instead of `~/Login`. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <configuration>
  <system.web>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="SignIn.aspx" defaultUrl="Welcome.aspx"  protection="All">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="lee" password="lee12345"/>
          <user name="add" password="add12345"/>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />      <!--his will restrict anonymous user access-->
    </authorization>

  </system.web>

  <location path="register.aspx">    <!--path here is path to your register.aspx page-->
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>       <!--this will allow access to everyone to register.aspx-->
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```